# I need UTC-8 / GMT-8 as php timezone. I CANNOT use America\Los Angeles because it has day light time savings

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

simple question, but cannot seem to find an answer

I need to set a timezone to UTC-8 and only UTC-8 (GMT-8 is actually the same). It cannot be a timezone with daylight time saving.

Now PHP does not seem to provide a way to set to GMT-8, when using `Etc/GMT-8` I get the wrong time (I get an offset way earlier) [like it says in the DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Now I could use GMT+8 to achieve GMT-8 (sounds odd but i Quote:

> Warning If you disregard the above warning, please also note that the
>   IANA timezone database that provides PHP's timezone support uses POSIX
>   style signs, which results in the Etc/GMT+n and Etc/GMT-n time zones
>   being reversed from common usage. For example, the time zone 8 hours
>   ahead of GMT that is used in China and Western Australia (among other
>   places) is actually Etc/GMT-8 in this database, not Etc/GMT+8 as you
>   would normally expect.

as there is no country in exactly UTC-8, i cannot put a country there...

so I use Etc/GMT+8 and cross the fingers they wont change it?

Comment: You can try `Pacific/Pitcairn`. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC−08:00), it uses standard time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can absolutely use `Etc/GMT+8` for a time zone that is fixed to UTC-8.  No, it won't change.  IANA time zone names are *identifiers*, and they are guaranteed to not be removed from the tz database.

That said, I'd ask you to question *why* you need a UTC-8 fixed offset time zone:

- Is it because you are referencing time on [Pitcairn Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitcairn_Islands)  (population 49)?  If so, use `Pacific/Pitcairn`.
- Is it because you are calculating time for a ship at sea that is traveling between 112.5°W and 127.5°W latitude?  If so, use `Etc/GMT+8`.
- Is it because you think DST isn't important, or you don't like it, or you were given a requirement that doesn't include it, etc?  Sorry, but like it or not - the people who physically occupy these areas do use DST.  If you elect not to, your clock will disagree with theirs for a considerable part of the year.  Use `America/Los_Angeles`, `America/Tijuana`, `America/Vancouver`, `America/Dawson`, or `America/Whitehorse`.

Comment: I know of at least one API that provides their dates in "UTC-8" so we need to parse them accordingly to ensure the dates we present to DST users are accurate.